# Grunt Browserify - Executing a script between two library loads

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, gruntjs, browserify

I am using grunt-browserify for handling requires server-side before serving an unique JS to the client.

Like exposed [here](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify/blob/master/examples/complex/Gruntfile.js), I want to load my libraries with a shim and put them altogether in a "vendor.js", then load my app's JS, execute the requires and put the result in a "app.js", and then use concat to get them together in a "main.js" file for the client.

The problem is that I am using jquery, jquery mobile and backbone. In order to make jqm and backbone usable together, I must disable jqm router before loading the jqm lib. With simple script tags, I used to **load in order jQuery, then a javascript which disables jQM router, then jQM, and then backbone**.

Now I do not know how to tell browserify to load the scripts in the same order. Here is my gruntfile (browserify part):

```
browserify: {
  vendor: {
    src: ['client/lib/**.js'],
    dest: 'client/build/vendor.js',
    options: {
      shim: {
        jquery: {
          path: 'client/lib/jquery-1.11.0.js',
          exports: '$'
        },
        'jquery.mobile.config': {
          path: 'client/lib/jquery.mobile-config.js',
          exports: null,
          depends: {
            jquery: '$'
          }
        },
        'jquery.mobile': {
          path: 'client/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js',
          exports: 'jqm',
          depends: {
            jquery: '$',
            'jquery.mobile.config' : 'jquery.mobile.config'
          }
        },
        underscore: {
          path: 'client/lib/underscore.js',
          exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
          path: 'client/lib/backbone.js',
          exports: 'Backbone',
          depends: {
            underscore: 'underscore'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  app: {
    files: {
      'client/app/**.js': ['client/build/app.js']
    }
  }
},
```

And here is the jquery.mobile.config script :

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

    // Remove page from DOM when it's being replaced
    $('div[data-role="page"]').on('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
        $(event.currentTarget).remove();
    });
});
```

In short, I try to do that : [Backbone + JQuery Mobile + RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946376/backbone-jquery-mobile-requirejs?rq=1) but with grunt-browserify instead of requirejs

Answer (score 0):

I found an hacky solution which consists of concatenating the jqm conf script at the beginning of jquery-mobile before browserifying it.

```
concat: {
  test: {
    options: {
      separator: ';'
    },
    src : ['client/lib/jqm/jquery.mobile-config.js', 'client/lib/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js'],
    dest: 'client/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.configured.js'
  }

...

browserify: {
  lib: {
    src: ['client/lib/*.js'],
    dest: 'client/build/temp/lib.js',
    options: {
      shim: {
        jquery: {
          path: 'client/lib/jquery-1.11.0.js',
          exports: '$'
        },
        'jquery.mobile': {
          path: 'client/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.configured.js',
          exports: '$',
          depends: {
            jquery: '$'
          }
        },
        underscore: {
          path: 'client/lib/underscore.js',
          exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
          path: 'client/lib/backbone.js',
          exports: 'Backbone',
          depends: {
            jquery: '$',
            underscore: '_'
          }
```

This works, avoids from modifying any library directly, but feels very hacky. If someone comes up with something better it would be nice